# Can I make table from other table elements?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Am I able to make a separated table filled with elements from other tables in Lua? Like this:

```
TableA = { a=1, b=2, c=3 }
TableB = { John=4, Jane =5 }
TableC = { x = "asd", y = "dsa", z = "sda" }

TableAll = { TableA.a, TableB.John, TableC.x}
```

It's a general example, but may work. I'm not sure in it.

Comment: I don't quite follow the issue you're having. Your code above seems *[to work](http://codepad.org/Akpo9FJh)*. Are you expecting different output?

Comment: @greatwolf I didn't know what to expect. I just wasn't sure that a table can reach another's key-value pairs. I know that I should have tried to run the code but I think thought that if I ask it, this question might be useful for beginner LUA users later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason why that wouldn't work?

All that `tablename.key` does is access an element of a table. This is a value; the fact that it came from a table is *completely irrelevant.* The value returned by `tablename.key` is no different than the value `5`, `nil`, `true`, `"some string"`, or any other value in Lua.

You can initialize a table with values; it doesn't matter where those values come from.

Comment: If I'd know, why it wouldn't work, I either would answer my own question, or wouldn't even ask it. ;) thank you anyway! I just wasn't sure that a table can reach another's key-value pairs.